# Is there an explanation for a change in behavior in applying MD5 hash to a set of files in parallel in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, io, md5

All!

I'm trying to find a faster method of calculation the MD5 sum of a large set of files, in order to identify duplicates for personal purposes.

I'm using Timothy Macintha fast hash implementation ([here](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php)) to get the job done.

I've tried three different approaches while applying the md5 sum to each file: iterating over the set, using stream, and using parallelStream.

What I found out is that on small set with large files, the parallel approach outperforms the other two by large and far.

But, if the set is very big with smaller files, the conventional and stream approaches are much faster.

The results (in milliseconds per file for each approach) can be seen below:
[image: inof]

Is there an reason for the change in performance for the parallel approach?

Does storing the md5 sums in a new set can adversely affect any of the listed approaches?

The code I'm using for the three approaches are as follows:

```
private static long applyHash(Set<File> files) {
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    files.stream()
            .forEach(file -> {
                try {
                    MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(file));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    Long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return (end - start);
}

private static long applyParallelHash(Set<File> files) {
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    files.parallelStream()
            .forEach(file -> {
                try {
                    MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(file));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    Long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return (end - start);
}

private static long applyConventionalHash(Set<File> files) {
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (File file:files) {
        try {
            MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(file));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    return (end - start);
}
```

Comment: My guess is it's to do with the seeking and caching behaviour of the physical disk. For larger files, it's more likely that the next segment to be read is from a file which you already started reading, so the disk can more easily predict what to pre-emptively load into the cache.

Comment: By the way, MD5 was broken over 20 years ago; cryptographers have been recommending against it since as far back as 1996. So you should not be using it except to maintain legacy systems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Overview_of_security_issues

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks a lot for your reply. In fact I picked up the md5 sum only because it's the least complex to compute, as I'm only looking for something to identify the contents of a file.

Answer (score 0):

I did a look into the source code of the MD5 library you've mentioned, what I understand is that MD5.getHash use blocking operation from the old io api (FilterInputStream), which results in a bad performance while working with parallel streams.

For better understanding, have a look into the 'Blocking vs. Non-blocking IO' section in https://dzone.com/articles/java-nio-vs-io

Comment: This doesn't explain why `parallelStream` is faster for the small set of larger files.